# Prove that the difference between a continuous function and its interpolation polynomial..?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

Let $ g \in C^2 [x,y] $ and $ P $ be its interpolation linear polynomial at $ a_0 $ and $ a_1 $ in $ [x,y] $. Prove that $ \lVert g-P\rVert _\infty < 1/8(a_1-a_0)^2B $ where $ \lvert g''(x)\rvert<B $ for all $ x \in [a,b] $.

I can't think of how to prove this. I am not sure which method to use.

Comment: Is it $|g''(x)|<B$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, or $|g''(t)|<B$ for all $t \in [x,y]$ ? or $|g''(t)|<B$ for all $t \in [a_0,a_1]$

Comment: It's the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(x)=(x-a_0)(x-a_1)$, $g(x)$ is not bounded when $x \mapsto \infty$. So there is a real number $u$ such that $g(u)>1/4 (a_0-a_1)^2$, and such that $a_0,a_1 \in [-u,u].$

For all $x \in [-u,u], g''(x)=2$, so $B=2$.

$g(a_0)=g(a_1)=0$ implies $P=0$.

So $\|g-P\|_{\infty}\geq g(u)>1/4 (a_0-a_1)^2=1/8(a_0-a_1)^2B$

So, it seems to be false.

Comment: thanks for answering marco. I don't understand where the $g(x)=(x-a_0)(x-a_1)$ came from; are you using the trapezoidal method?

Comment: @user1961722 He is just using $g$ as a counterexample. The thing is that your problem likely has a typo and the $||\cdot||_\infty$ is really the norm on $[a_0,a_1]$ instead of $[x,y]$.